# FFmpeg recover_mp4 help

Tags: ffmpeg, video, encoding, mp4

ive been using ffmpeg and recover mp4 to try and restore a dashcam video from a car accident. im a beginner using this method/ software and im running into this issue. not sure how to "increase analyzeduration and probesize"  any and all help appreciated ASAP

```
C:\ffmpeg-2023-03-20-git-57afccc0ef-essentials_build\recovery\bin>ffmpeg.exe -r 25.000 -i result.h264 -i result.aac -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -c:v copy -c:a copy result.mp4
ffmpeg version 2023-03-20-git-57afccc0ef-essentials_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 12.2.0 (Rev10, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-sdl2 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libvpl --enable-libgme --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-librubberband
  libavutil      58.  4.100 / 58.  4.100
  libavcodec     60.  6.101 / 60.  6.101
  libavformat    60.  4.100 / 60.  4.100
  libavdevice    60.  2.100 / 60.  2.100
  libavfilter     9.  4.100 /  9.  4.100
  libswscale      7.  2.100 /  7.  2.100
  libswresample   4. 11.100 /  4. 11.100
  libpostproc    57.  2.100 / 57.  2.100
[h264 @ 0000025867b3dac0] Format h264 detected only with low score of 1, misdetection possible!
[h264 @ 0000025867b4f940] missing picture in access unit with size 23
[h264 @ 0000025867b4f940] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000025867b3dac0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264, none): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' (0) and 'probesize' (5000000) options
Input #0, h264, from 'result.h264':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #0:0: Video: h264, none, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn
[aac @ 0000025867c0e5c0] Format aac detected only with low score of 1, misdetection possible!
result.aac: End of file

C:\ffmpeg-2023-03-20-git-57afccc0ef-essentials_build\recovery\bin>
C:\ffmpeg-2023-03-20-git-57afccc0ef-essentials_build\recovery\bin>
```

Comment: Add `-analyzeduration 100M -probesize 100M` before each of `-i result.h264` and `-i result.aac`.

Comment: Although it looks like your aac file is very short.